# Staying logged in (keeping cookies) WebDriver/Codeception/Selenium

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception

**Setps:**

- 1.Login.
- 2.Go to Profile.
- 3.Go to Bookings.
- 4.Iterate through bookings till something is found.
- 5.Do some other stuff on the booking detail page

**Problem at 4.**

When clicking on any Booking it redirects me to the login page, even thoght I was logged in first.

As requested all steps are here.

```
private function executeLogin(\AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('/de/account/login');

    $I->fillField('#_username', 'user');
    $I->fillField('#_password', 'somepw');
    $I->click('body > div > main > div > form > div > div > button');
}


public function logIn(\AcceptanceTester $I )
{
    $I->wantTo('Log-in to My Website');

    $this->executeLogin($I);
}


public function goToBookings(\AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->wantTo('Go to all my Bookings Page');

    $flyOutButton = '.nav-main__link-flyout.nav-account';
    $myBookingsButton = '/html/body/div/header/div/div/div/nav/ul/li[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/a';

    $I->moveMouseOver($flyOutButton);
    $I->moveMouseOver($myBookingsButton);
    $I->click($myBookingsButton);

}

public function checkForExtra(\AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->wantTo('Go through all Bookings and check if Extras are Available');

    $extrasCounter = 1;

    do{
        // $I->click('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div['.$extrasCounter.']/a/div/article/div/div/div/button');
        $I->click('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div['.$extrasCounter.']/a');

        //TODO Here it Redirects to the Login // Should go to the booking details Page
        $grabExtrasID = $I->grabMultiple('#add-extras-link');
        $totalExtras = count($grabExtrasID);

        $extrasCounter++;

        if ($totalExtras === 1){
            break;
        }

        codecept_debug($totalExtras);

        $I->moveBack();

    }while($totalExtras == 0);
}
```

The `$I->Click` is where i get logged out / redirected to the login. And not to the whole booking details page.

**Console Output**

```
    I click "/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/div/article/div/div/div/button"
 I grab multiple "#add-extras-link"
 I move back
  /de/account/bookings
  0
 I click "/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/a/div/article/div/div/div/button"
 I grab multiple "#add-extras-link"
 I move back
  /de/account/bookings
  0
 I click "/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/a/div/article/div/div/div/button"
 I grab multiple "#add-extras-link"
 I move back
  /de/account/bookings
  0
 I click "/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/a/div/article/div/div/div/button"
 I grab multiple "#add-extras-link"
 I move back
  /de/account/bookings
  0
 I click "/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[5]/a/div/article/div/div/div/button"
 I grab multiple "#add-extras-link"
 I move back
  /de/account/bookings
  0
```

As you can see the 0 indicates it found 0 classes from what im looking for. 
There are at least 3 bookings with the class. 
This is because It does not even go to the booking details page.

I hope this makes sense, please let me know if there is other Information you need.

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone ? I know its a pretty special case.

Comment: Please add the code of steps 1-3 and the code which glues them together.

Comment: All code till that point added. The interesting thing is that on the actually  website it works. But only the automated one, it just won't.  Im not sure what could cause the Problem. But i'm really curious.

Comment: 1) Check if login was successful 2) Add code of the test to your question 3) Execute this test with -vvv flag and look for anything unexpected in output.

Comment: Ensure that the user actually logged in (e.g. check for a logout button being available after the login form is submitted). I've got hundreds of tests requiring the actor to be logged in and it's working just fine.